# Shape error as I try to plot the decision boundary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, supervised-learning

From my [wine-dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cLBApgCT86yH_FN824FXxom6-TgWYy2GtEoFatxuPAg/edit?usp=sharing), I am trying to plot a decision boundary between 2 columns which is described by the snippet:

```
X0, X1 = X[:, 10], Y
```

I have taken the following code from [scikit svm plot tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html) and modified to replace with my variable names/index. However when I run the following code, I get an error saying:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 11, the number of features at training time
```

with error stack as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "test-wine.py", line 120, in <module>
    cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
File "test-wine.py", line 96, in plot_contours
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
File "/home/suhail/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 548, in predict
    y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
File "/home/suhail/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 308, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
File "/home/suhail/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 459, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 2 should be equal to 11, the number of features at training time
```

I cannot understand the reason for the above error. Here is the code that I have modified.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv').values

x_data_shape = data.shape[0]
y_data_shape = data.shape[1]

X = data[:, 0:y_data_shape-1]
Y = data[:, y_data_shape-1]


############### PLOT DECISION BOUNDARY SVM #############

def make_meshgrid(x, y, h=.02):
    """Create a mesh of points to plot in

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: data to base x-axis meshgrid on
    y: data to base y-axis meshgrid on
    h: stepsize for meshgrid, optional

    Returns
    -------
    xx, yy : ndarray
    """
    x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
    y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                        np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
    return xx, yy


def plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy, **params):
    """Plot the decision boundaries for a classifier.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax: matplotlib axes object
    clf: a classifier
    xx: meshgrid ndarray
    yy: meshgrid ndarray
    params: dictionary of params to pass to contourf, optional
    """
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    out = ax.contourf(xx, yy, Z, **params)
    return out


C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
models = (SVC(kernel='linear', C=C),
        SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C),
        SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C))
models = (clf.fit(X, Y) for clf in models)

titles = ('SVC with linear kernel',
        'SVC with RBF kernel',
        'SVC with polynomial (degree 3) kernel')

fig, sub = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.4)

X0, X1 = X[:, 10], Y
xx, yy = make_meshgrid(X0, X1)

for clf, title, ax in zip(models, titles, sub.flatten()):
    plot_contours(ax, clf, xx, yy,
                cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.8)
    ax.scatter(X0, X1, c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, s=20, edgecolors='k')
    ax.set_xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
    ax.set_ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
    ax.set_xlabel('Alcohol Content')
    ax.set_ylabel('Quality')
    ax.set_xticks(())
    ax.set_yticks(())
    ax.set_title(title)

plt.show()
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

You trained the classifiers with all 11 features,
 but you provide only 2 features for the evaluation of the classifier which happens when `Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])` is called from within the `plot_contours` method. 
To evaluate a classifier trained with 11 features, you need to provide all 11 features. This is what your error message indicates.

So in order to make the snippet work for you, you should limit yourself to two features (otherwise plotting two-dimensional decision boundaries does not make sense anyway), e.g by using

```
X = data[:, :2]
Y = data[:, y_data_shape-1]
```

when reading your data.

Note that the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html) you referred to also uses only two features:

```
# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
# Take the first two features. We could avoid this by using a two-dim dataset
X = iris.data[:, :2]
y = iris.target
```